# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError : syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

When I run this code I face this error:Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError : syntax error, unexpected end of file

point)in NGIX i dont have any problem but now I want to run it in laravelhomestead but it throws me this error.

point2)this is content.php file in router

```
<?php
```

function extView($route)
{
$texts = [https://www.i-b.com/];

```
$mercati = ['banking-finance-fintech', 'insurance-insurtech', 'consumer-goods', 'industrial-goods', 'energy-utilities-infrastructure', 'luxury-fashion-design', 'sport-media-entertainment', 'pharma-medicine-healthcare', 'technology-telecom', 'public-sector', 'social-sector', 'private-equity'];

$servizi = ['strategy-governance', 'competitive-intelligence', 'innovation-management', 'ai-bigdata', 'marketing', 'sponsorship', 'sales', 'brand-communication', 'hr-organization', 'sustainability', 'ma'];

if (array_key_exists($route, $texts)) {
    return view('general-list', {$texts[$route]});
} else if (in_array($route, $mercati)) {
    return view('general-list', {$texts['banking-finance-fintech']});
} else if (in_array($route, $servizi)) {
    return view('general-list', {$texts['sponsorship']});
} else {
    abort(404);
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFMTv.png)

Comment: What's the code you're running?

Comment: I edit it and add the code

Comment: Can you also add the full error stack trace?

Comment: Also, `endif` isn't a thing in PHP

Comment: That's the point. PHP thinks he's closing the function's bracket before doing what he was supposed to do with the "endif" constant

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the use of `endif` keyword that marks the end of an `if` statement that was started with syntax containing colon like so

```
if(...):
//..
elseif:
//..
else:
//.. 
endif;
```

However since you are using curly braces, the use of `endif` at the end of the condition block is incorrect syntax hence the `syntax error`

To fix this error, simply reemove the `endif` keyword from your code:

```
<?php


function extView($route)
{
    $texts = [];

$mercati = ['banking-finance-fintech', 'insurance-insurtech', 'consumer-goods', 'industrial-goods', 'energy-utilities-infrastructure', 'luxury-fashion-design', 'sport-media-entertainment', 'pharma-medicine-healthcare', 'technology-telecom', 'public-sector', 'social-sector', 'private-equity'];

    $servizi = ['strategy-governance', 'competitive-intelligence', 'innovation-management', 'ai-bigdata', 'marketing', 'sponsorship', 'sales', 'brand-communication', 'hr-organization', 'sustainability', 'ma'];

    if (array_key_exists($route, $texts)) {
        return view('general-list', {$texts[$route]});
    } else if (in_array($route, $mercati)) {
        return view('general-list', {$texts['banking-finance-fintech']});
    } else if (in_array($route, $servizi)) {
        return view('general-list', {$texts['sponsorship']});
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
    // dont use endif here

} 
?>
```

Comment: No it did not work